# What is the correct signature for DllMain in rust?

Tags: winapi, rust

I am trying to create a cdylib in rust and defined this function for the DllMain

```
use winapi::shared::minwindef::*;
use winapi::um::winnt::DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "stdcall" fn DllMain(_h_inst_dll: HINSTANCE, fdw_reason: DWORD, _lpv_reserved: LPVOID) -> BOOL {
    if fdw_reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH {
        //do stuff
    }
    return 1;
}
```

But the code isn't being run when the dll is attached to a process, is there something wrong with the signature? When I inspected the dll I noticed that the function name is automatically exported by `#[no_mangle]` is there a way I can avoid this?

Comment: You don't want it without `#[no_mangle]`, or Windows can't recognize it as `DllMain`.

Comment: @ken Windows doesn't care about the symbol name. The OS loader parses out the `AddressOfEntryPoint` entry of the [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header32) and uses that, irrespective of the symbol name, or whether the symbol even has a name. This isn't just theory either: It's what we are using **all the time**. A standard DLL project created with Visual Studio uses the symbol `_DllMainCRTStartup` as its entry point, that eventually calls into the client-defined `DllMain`.